# Converted hair particles (to mesh), unable to add materials (colors/texture)

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I was sculpting/modeling a reed using particle hair system.
After I converted the hair to mesh, it lost its material (color texture).

I went to the material properties to add the color, but it keeps showing as a black line. I tried deselcting it and went to check other objects, it still looked the same. I made sure that I am on a correct viewport to see it rendered.

What could I do to add color/material to the hair (converted mesh)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is that there are no faces that you can texture if you hit the "Convert to Mesh" button. You have a few options 1) use an object (e.g. a plane) for the "Render As" particle settings. The button will change to "Make Instances Real" and create a mesh with faces 2) You can use the *Particle Instance* modifier on a plane object. 3) Use a GN modifier on your converted mesh to extrude the edges and create geometry that you can texture (*Mesh to Curve* node + *Curves to Mesh* node with a *Curve Circle* node as *Profile*). Keep plane/curve circle low poly because it will get multiplied